# python skimage.measure.label leads to segment fault in linux environment

Tags: python, linux, fault, segment

I use skimage.measure.label in my python program to process a series images, the code is:

```
for i in range(n):
    label_img, num = label(img[i], return_num = True)
```

then report segmental fault. And I rewrite the label function using bfs method, then success. I wonder if the the original label function is a dfs method. I think the dfs method leads to a Mem overflow, And if so , how to do with this problem?

Comment: Your question lacks detail. If you wrote the `label` function, please provide the code. What is a bfs and/or a dfs method?

Comment: it works ok for me in `skimage 0.13.0`, ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, I rewrited the label function in bfs method, and it works well.